# why boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket() cannot be const

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket() const` is returning `_socket` which is of type `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` is giving me this error

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&’ from a temporary of type ‘const boost::reference_wrapper<const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >’
```

`socket()` function is only getter and is not altering the state of this object so why does it fire error if I make it `const` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the function is returning a reference to an object.  When the const member function is called, the returned reference must also be const.

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket const& socket() const`

However, depending on what you want to do with that socket reference, you might have to return a non-const reference, in which case another option is to declare the getter function as non-const or declare the socket `mutable` in the class definition

`mutable boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_`

Comment: `When const member function is called the returned reference must also be const` !! Well I thought that function must not alter object's state. never heard that its mandatory to return a `const ref`.

Comment: @DiproSen: If the returned reference is not `const`, you could use it to call non-`const` functions on the referenced object, hence circumventing the `const`ness of it all.

Comment: but If the returned reference is not const it may change the state of `returned object` but not the `this` object of that member function

Comment: @DiproSen: When a member function is marked `const`, it treats all members of the object as `const` as well.  This prevents you from calling non-const member functions on those members as well.  It also prevents you from initializing a non-const reference to one of those fields.